# Keyboard not registering repeated keystrokes

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Today I have encountered a strange problem with my keyboard:

Suddenly the keyboard stopped registering keypresses after pressing them the first time.

I mean if I pressed <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> it registered normally, but <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> only registered as <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Every button was the same, for example the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> was easy to test because of the indicator light.

It was not an issue with the text editor I used, it was present in the whole operating system.

I'm using Windows 8, and a PS/2 keyboard.

After restarting the PC everything went back to normal, but this got me curious as I was unable to find others on the internet with similar symptoms.

Anyone have any idea what could have been the cause of this?

To avoid confusion note, that the "repeater function" of the keyboard was working fine, so when I *pressed and holded* a character key, it repeated just fine. The problem was only with *repeatedly pressing* the the same button.

Comment: There is no way to tell the reason this happen with the information you have supplied.  If I were to take a wild guess I would say the keyboard is going bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off Filter Keys fixed this issue for me on my brand-new Windows 8 laptop. Thank you; this was driving me insane.